# Is it mandatory to have monitor connected to remote desktop system?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I plan to do a remote desktop to another system from my laptop. In my laptop I have an additional monitor connected. When I do remote desktop I plan to use "Use all my monitors for remote session" option so that remote system detects 2 monitors. In this setup, is it mandatory to have a physical monitor connected to the remote system? Can I connect to a system without any physical monitors and it will use both monitors connected to my laptop? Both laptop and Remote system are running on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows Remote Desktop does not use the physical video outputs nor the physical keyboard/mouse inputs. When a session is attached to RDP it is automatically detached from console, and vice versa.